# What's the name of the card game in Final Fantasy 8?

Tags: final-fantasy-8

In Final Fantasy 8 there was a really addictive card game that kept me occupied for many, many days.

The basics of the game were:

1. There was a board with 9 cells.
2. You could select a given amount of cards at the start of the game (I forget how many).
3. Each card had a number on each of its edges ranging from 1-A.
4. Players take turns placing their selected cards into an unoccupied cell of their choice.
5. If an adjacent card owned by the other player has a lower score on the touching edge, you gain control of the card.
6. Player with control of the most cards once all cells are filled wins.

There were also some other tactics that involved a bit of basic math to take over two adjacent cards regardless of score if you met certain criteria, etc.

Does anyone know if this game was based off a real card game? I'd like to track it down. A digital version would be even better!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Triple Triad was designed by Hiroyuki Ito, the battle designer for FFVIII, and wasn't based on a specific card game as far as I know.
It did however spawn a physical version, described [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15957/final-fantasy-viii-triple-triad)
Also check out [Triple Triad Online](http://www.triple-triad-online.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the online version you sent through seems to be primarily in French. Also their server seems to be down and has been since July. The name will help me out overall though :)

Answer (score 8):

It is called [*Triple Triad*](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Triple_Triad).

> The Triple Triad (トリプルトライアード, Toripuru Toraiādo?) is a popular card game in Final Fantasy VIII. According to the Final Fantasy VIII Ultimania the card game was created by a psychic named Orlan who modified fortune-telling cards for use in a game, coining the official name "Triple Triad."[1] Triple Triad was initially played among soldiers, but spread to the common people and by the time of Final Fantasy VIII's events, the game is extremely popular among all age groups.
>
> Triple Triad is played on a three-by-three (3x3) square grid of blank spaces, where cards will be placed as the game progresses. The cards depict various characters, monsters, and bosses from the game. Each card has four numbers (known as Ranks) placed in top left corner; each number corresponds to one of the four sides of the card. These numbers range from one to nine, the letter A representing ten. On the top right of the card there is sometimes an elemental symbol representing the card's element. The elements are Earth, Fire, Water, Poison, Holy, Lightning, Wind, and Ice.

It is not based on any real game. Bandai-Namco did make a physical version at one point, but it was a limited, Japan-only run.

Answer (score 4):

For those finding this question in 2017+, Triple Triad is now available as part of the official Final Fantasy Portal App from Square Enix, found [here](http://www.square-enix.com/ffportal/na/index.html).  It has cards referencing characters from all mainline FF games and lets players compete online.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the name of the game is Triple Triad.

There's an executable version I found online called "Triple Triad Gold". It works on WinXP, I don't know about other operating systems.